# Write xml to file

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I know that there are many same questions here, but it doesn't solve my problem

I want to write xml to file. Writing Android app on Xamarin.

I already create it

I create xml like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement el = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Order"));
el.SetAttribute("CallConfirm", "1");
el.SetAttribute("PayMethod", "Безнал");
el.SetAttribute("QtyPerson", "");
el.SetAttribute("Type", "2");
el.SetAttribute("PayStateID", "0");
el.SetAttribute("Remark", "{Comment}");
el.SetAttribute("RemarkMoney", "0");
el.SetAttribute("TimePlan", "");
el.SetAttribute("Brand", "1");
el.SetAttribute("DiscountPercent", "0");
el.SetAttribute("BonusAmount", "0");
el.SetAttribute("Department", "");

XmlElement el2 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Customer"));
el2.SetAttribute("Login", "");
el2.SetAttribute("FIO", "{FIO}");

XmlElement el3 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Address"));
el3.SetAttribute("CityName", "{CityName}");
el3.SetAttribute("StationName", "");
el3.SetAttribute("StreetName", "{StreetName}");
el3.SetAttribute("House", "{HouseName}");
el3.SetAttribute("Corpus", "");
el3.SetAttribute("Building", "");
el3.SetAttribute("Flat", "{FlatName}");
el3.SetAttribute("Porch", "");
el3.SetAttribute("Floor", "");
el3.SetAttribute("DoorCode", "");

XmlElement el4 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Phone"));
el4.SetAttribute("Code", "{Code}");
el4.SetAttribute("Number", "{Phone}");

XmlElement el5 = (XmlElement)el.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Products"));

XmlElement el6 = (XmlElement)el5.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Product"));
el6.SetAttribute("Code", "{ProductCode}");
el6.SetAttribute("Qty", "{QTY}");

Console.WriteLine ("TUT");
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

I try to write to file like this:

```
File.WriteAllText("myFile.xml",doc.ToString());
```

And have this error -  `Access to the path "/myFile.xml" is denied.`

I try to write file like this, but it doesn't help.

I don't see file on device (try to find it via explorer)

```
 var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "myFile.xml");
File.WriteAllText(filePath, doc.ToString());
```

How I can solve this problem?

Thank's for help

Comment: Have you setup the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions?

Comment: There is a `XmlDocument.Save()`.  This error is related to the file system not XML, check storage permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to save the file with an invalid path: `/myFile.xml`.

Try using a fully qualified path, by doing the following:

```
var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "myFile.xml");
File.WriteAllText(filePath, doc.ToString());
```

Comment: my file is on the root of project, how I need to write path?

Comment: I try this, but I don't see  file when try to find it in solution

Comment: This file won't be in your solution, it will be on the device/emulator.

Comment: How I can see what in it?

Comment: Either read the file again and print it to the console.  Or on the device/emulator navigate to the location the file is being stored and download/copy it to your pc.

Comment: Don't see this file on my device

Comment: Okay, so change the path to something public (ie. your downloads folder).

Comment: On SD card or Internal memory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96989/discussion-between-eugene-and-johan).